# Sage--use spkg coxeter3 in Sage notebook

Tags: sagemath

I want to use the well-known coxeter3  package (http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~ducloux/coxeter/coxeter3/english/coxeter3_e.html) in sage-notebook. I've tried 'i' and 'f' but doesn't work, so far I couldn't find a 'good' answer online.

How to install the package so that I can use it in sage-notebook?

Comment: You can try running the Coxeter package on SageMathCloud https://cocalc.com/ or contact sage support: http://www.sagemath.org/help.html . In particular, ask your question to the google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sage-support

Comment: Software installation is not on-topic here, even for packages commonly used by mathematicians.  However using `coxeter3` or similar Sage extensions to accomplish a specific mathematical task could well be on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed Sage from source or from a binary
for Linux or macOS, you should be able to install
the coxeter3 package by opening a terminal and running

```
sage -i coxeter3
```

(type `sage -i coxeter3` and hit the RETURN or ENTER key).

Providing you have the necessary development tools
available, this will install the package for your
version of Sage, and next time you start either the
Sage REPL (read-eval-print loop, or command-line interface
in the terminal), or the SageNB notebook, or the Jupyter
notebook with the SageMath kernel, you will be able to
use the functionality of the coxeter3 package.

This also assumes that your shell is configured so that
when you type `sage` in a terminal, this launches Sage.

If this is not the case, you need to open a terminal and
run something like

```
sudo ln -sf /path/to/sagedir/sage /usr/local/bin
```

where `/path/to/sagedir` should be replaced by the path to
the Sage directory (and you might need to type in your user
password for your user account on that Mac). If you don't
know what the path is to the Sage directory, you can obtain
it by launching Sage and running, in Sage,

```
print SAGE_ROOT
```

Comment: I did '$ sage -i coxeter3' in the (mac) terminal as you said, what I got is ' -bash: -i: command not found '

Comment: @W.Z.Zhang -- I edited my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Leilièvre -- Thanks for your help,   after doing this:   now if I type 'sage' in the terminal, It will not give me' -bash: sage: command not found', which is good, but still when I do' sage -i', I get '-bash: -i: command not found'

Comment: I am puzzled by the bash error you get. As an alternative, you could start Sage (either using the Sage REPL, the SageNB notebook, or the Jupyter notebook with the SageMath kernel), and run `!sage -i coxeter3` (starting a command with `!` inside Sage lets you run a shell command from within Sage).

Comment: This is what I got for '! sage -i coxeter3' ----" xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun "    And I've updated the question .        thanks a lot